# IOS Push Notification disable/enable on the basis of key

Tags: ios, push-notification, silent

1. Just wondering whether there is any way to disable/enable a push notification when it is received.

   For e.g :- When i receive a push notification then i first check in my app whether in notification setting i have enabled or disabled the notification.
2. There can also be multiple notification settings like

   - To disable a friend request notification
   - To disable message notification

So while sending a notification is there any way to append notificationType like if its for friend request or messaging.

Then after checking the notification type and its corresponding setting in the app, showing or discarding the notification.

Comment: for point-2 -In your server, you can set a flag like which user enabled notification for friend request and from server side you can send notification to only those user who allowed to  receive that type of notification

Comment: And if i want to send the Notification just to save message in the application cache. So that i do not have to get that message from the server again.

In that case?

Comment: You can send message with notification in notification payload

Comment: And will it show the message to the user? 

I mean if notification is off it should not show push notification to the user.

It should just only cache the messgage.

Comment: Notification sending logic is based on server, keep a flag for enable /disable  based on user setting in phone. On notification arrival do whatever you want based on payload keys. Keep meaningful notification type key for proper handling. Send silent notification from server if you want to send a notification without any alert etc . or keeps an attribute for notifications which should be shown as alert or not

Comment: You can not get device token if notification is disabled from setting

Comment: I am just confused that on notification arrival. How can i stop notification from being shown to user?

Comment: You can't receive  notification in background without showing to user

Comment: Yes that i know. I mean if it possible to decide at notification arrival whether to show notification to user or not?

Comment: You can only  do it if app is foreground.

Comment: I have handled it already. But i am asking in the case when app is not running.

Comment: You can set this logic to your server...send notification to only those user who are enabled

Comment: you can only decide notification display if the app is in forground state. otherwise its default behaviour will be addopted like banner or locked screen notification

Comment: No you can't while app is not running

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this just in client side itself. Because once notification arrives it is handled by iOS and displayed in notification centre (or any other type as per user setting). App will not get the notification info, unless it is running.

You can have this as settings in Client and sync it with server to have a check there before pushing the notifications.