# Is it possible to disble push notifications by type/category on iOS? (APN or FCM)

Tags: ios, firebase, notifications, apple-push-notifications, apn

In my aplication I have 2 types of notifications and the user has the option to disable or enable each one inside the app. For example if the user wants to receive only the type1 notification, he will go to the settings and he will disable there, but he will receive notifications of type2. I saw in Spotify and the user is able to disable notifications by type.

My problem is that, from what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510578/enable-or-disable-iphone-push-notifications-inside-the-app) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747760/ios-push-notification-disable-enable-on-the-basis-of-key) I'm only able to do it server side. I can't do it on client side is that correct?

The unregisterPushNotifications disables everything. So in my server I would have a "flag" to send it or not.

If I use FCM (Firebase) will I be able to disable notifications by type or will I have to make the same thing as if I user APNs?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the service you are using to send push notifications, many will include the concept of "channels" or "groups" that your users can subscribe to. But, yes, this is managed on the server side, not through the push notification registration.

Comment: the alternative I found was using APNs to send silent notifications and when I receive a notification, I create a Local Notification. it works.

Answer (score 0):

For those who wonder how I managed to do it.

The alternative I found was using APNs to send silent notifications and when I receive a notification, I create a Local Notification.
I receive the silent notification, it triggers the method in AppDelegate and I read the data of the notification. If it is the type I want it to show up, I create a local notification and make it show up in the system. It was the best solution I found.